# Border rank of tensors

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms, tensor-products, tensors, tensor-rank

Can anyone help me find the rank and border rank of the following tensor:

\begin{align}
T=a_{11}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{11}+a_{12}\otimes b_{21}\otimes c_{11}+a_{11}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{12}\\
   +a_{12}\otimes b_{22}\otimes c_{12}+a_{21}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{21}+a_{21}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{22}
\end{align}

It's the product of two matrices $\mathit{A}$ and $\mathit{B}$ where the entry in the last column and the last row of matrix $\mathit{A}$ i.e. $a_{22}$ equals zero(given by Bini). I know the answer, but I do not understand the procedure.

Comment: Is this for multiplication of triangular matrices? A little more context would be nice.

Comment: @Calle I have edited the question. You might be able to help me now. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I think the rank is 6 and the border rank is 5.

Comment: @Calle I know the answer. But, I don't understand the procedure for evaluating it. On page 5 of this paper, you can have a look at what I'm trying to say: http://issac-symposium.org/2014/tutorials/ISSAC2014_tutorial_handout_LeGall.pdf

Answer (score 0):

This question is very, very old, but nevertheless I think an answer might help people coming across. The Bini tensor is an excellent tensor to demonstrate some basic techniques to investigate rank and border rank for tensors.

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be finite dimensional, complex vector spaces.

First, recall that the *rank* $R(T)$ of a tensor $T \in A\otimes B \otimes C$ is defined as the minimal $r$ such that there exists vectors $u_1, \dots , u_r \in A$, $v_1, \dots , v_r \in B$ and $w_1, \dots w_r \in C$ such that
$$T = \sum_{i=1}^r u_i \otimes v_i \otimes w_i$$

The *border rank* $\underline{R}(T)$ is the minimal $r$ such that
$$T = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} T_\epsilon$$
where $R(T_\epsilon) \leq r$ for all  $\epsilon > 0$ (the limit can be taken for example in the Euclidean norm).

**Fact 1:** By definition, it is clear that *local* linear maps cannot enlarge the rank:
For $T \in A \otimes B\otimes C$ and linear maps $M_A: A \rightarrow A'$, $M_B: B \rightarrow B'$ and $M_C: C \rightarrow C'$ we have
$$R(T) \geq R\left((M_A\otimes M_B\otimes M_C) T\right)$$
The same holds true for the border rank.

**Fact 2:** A tensor $T \in A\otimes B \otimes C$ naturally defines a linear map $T_A : A^* \rightarrow B\otimes C$: For $T = \sum_{i=1}^r u_i \otimes v_i \otimes w_i$, define $T_A(\alpha) = \sum_{i=1}^r \alpha(u_i) \cdot v_i \otimes w_i$. This is called a *flattening*. With the same procedure, we also get linear maps $T_B$ and $T_C$. Every simple tensor of the form $a\otimes b \otimes c$ leads to a linear map of rank 1. Therefore, the rank of a flattening map of a tensor of rank $\leq r$ is at most $r$. That is, $R(T) \geq rank(T_A)$. The same is true for $T_B$ and $T_C$.
Indeed, the same holds for border rank and since for linear maps the rank is lower semicontinuous, we have $\underline{R}(T) \geq rank(T_A)$.

Let us now think about our specific tensor: Let $\lbrace a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{21} \rbrace$ be a basis of $A$ and similarly $\lbrace b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{21}, b_{22} \rbrace$ and $\lbrace c_{11}, c_{12}, c_{21}, c_{22} \rbrace$ bases for $B$ and $C$ and define

\begin{align}
T_{Bini}=a_{11}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{11}+a_{12}\otimes b_{21}\otimes c_{11}+a_{11}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{12}\\
   +a_{12}\otimes b_{22}\otimes c_{12}+a_{21}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{21}+a_{21}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{22}
\end{align}

Since it is written as a sum of $6$ simple tensors, its rank is at most $6$: $R(T_{Bini}) \leq 6$.

We will now show that it is exactly 6.

**Proposition 1:** $R(T_{Bini})\geq 6$ and consequently, $R(T_{Bini}) = 6$.

**Proof:** Assume it has actually rank at most 5, so we can write it as

$$T_{Bini} = u_1\otimes v_1 \otimes w_1 + \dots + u_5\otimes v_5 \otimes w_5$$

Clearly, if we write the $v_k$ as linear combinations of the basis vectors $b_{ij}$, for one of them the coefficient of $b_{21}$ is non-zero (else, we would never get the summand $a_{12}\otimes b_{21}\otimes c_{11}$). Say without loss of generality that
$$v_1 = c_1 b_{21} + w_1$$
for $w_1 \in \text{span}(b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{22})$ and $c_1 \neq 0$.

Define the linear map

$$M_1 : B \rightarrow B, b_{ij} \mapsto \begin{cases}b_{ij} &\text{ if } (i,j) \neq (2,1) \\ -\frac{1}{c_1}w_1 &\text{ else}\end{cases}$$

By construction, $M_1(v_1) = 0$, so,

$$(\text{id} \otimes M_1 \otimes \text{id}) T_{Bini} = u_2\otimes M_1(v_2) \otimes w_2 + \dots + u_5\otimes M_1 (v_5) \otimes w_5$$
has tensor rank at most 4. By definition of $M_1$, we also have
\begin{align}
(\text{id} \otimes M_1 \otimes \text{id})T_{Bini}=a_{11}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{11}+a_{12}\otimes M_1(b_{21})\otimes c_{11}+a_{11}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{12}\\
   +a_{12}\otimes b_{22}\otimes c_{12}+a_{21}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{21}+a_{21}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{22}
\end{align}
Again, we see that one of the vectors $M_1 (v_i)$ must have a non-zero $b_{22}$-coefficient. Else, the summand $a_{12}\otimes b_{22}\otimes c_{12}$ could not be there.

Now, the same strategy can be used to decrease the rank again: Without loss, assume
$$M_1(v_2) = c_2 b_{22} + w_2$$
$w_2 \in \text{span}(b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{21})$ and $c_2 \neq 0$ and define
$$M_2 : B \rightarrow B, b_{ij} \mapsto \begin{cases}b_{ij} &\text{ if } (i,j) \neq (2,2) \\ -\frac{1}{c_2}w_2 &\text{ else}\end{cases}$$

This has $M_1(v_2)$ in its kernel, therefore
$$(\text{id} \otimes M_2 \otimes \text{id})(\text{id} \otimes M_1 \otimes \text{id}) T_{Bini} = u_3\otimes M_2(M_1(v_3)) \otimes w_3 + \dots + u_5\otimes M_2(M_1 (v_5)) \otimes w_5$$
has rank at most 3.

Note that this tensor now is of the form
\begin{align}
(\text{id} \otimes M_2 \otimes \text{id})(\text{id} \otimes M_1 \otimes \text{id})T_{Bini}=a_{11}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{11}+a_{12}\otimes M_2(M_1(b_{21}))\otimes c_{11}+a_{11}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{12}\\
   +a_{12}\otimes M_2(b_{22})\otimes c_{12}+a_{21}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{21}+a_{21}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{22}
\end{align}

Now, we see why it was good that we chose $b_{21}$ and $b_{22}$ for the above procedure: The maps we applied only affect summands in this decomposition that "start" with $a_{12}$. So, by projecting out $a_{12}$ by using a local map on the first vector space, we can get rid of all terms with $M_i$'s and get a tensor which is supposed to have rank at most 3.

More formally, define the projector
$$\Pi : A \rightarrow A, a_{ij} \mapsto \begin{cases} a_{ij} &\text{ if } (i,j) \neq (1,2) \\ 0 &\text{ else}\end{cases}$$

Then, by **Fact 2**,
\begin{align}
S :=(\Pi \otimes \text{id} \otimes \text{id})(\text{id} \otimes M_2 \otimes \text{id})(\text{id} \otimes M_1 \otimes \text{id})T_{Bini}=a_{11}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{11}+a_{11}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{12}\\
   +a_{21}\otimes b_{11}\otimes c_{21}+a_{21}\otimes b_{12}\otimes c_{22}
\end{align}
has rank at most 3.

But we can observe that the flattening $S_C$ has image
$$\text{span}(a_{11}\otimes b_{11},a_{11}\otimes b_{12},  a_{21}\otimes b_{11}, a_{21}\otimes b_{12} )$$
which is four dimensional as span of four linearly independent vectors. By **Fact 2**, the tensor $S$ therefore has rank at least 4 -  a contradiction. $\square$

**Remark:** This proof method is a standard method to prove lower bounds on tensor rank and is called *substitution method*. The reason why this is called substitution method can be found for example [in these lecture notes by Markus Bläser](https://www-cc.cs.uni-saarland.de/media/lectures/S13/L-FastMatrixMultiplication/mm.pdf).

**Exercise:** Show with the exact same method that the so-called $W$-tensor $W = a_1 \otimes b_1 \otimes c_2 + a_1 \otimes b_2 \otimes c_1 + a_2 \otimes b_1 \otimes c_1$ has rank 3. This is an excellent exercise to convince yourself that you understood how the above proof works.

We now know the rank of $T_{Bini}$. Let's think about border rank now.

**Proposition 2:** $\underline{R}(T_{Bini}) \leq 5$

**Proof:** For every $\epsilon > 0$, let
\begin{align}
T(\epsilon) =\frac{1}{\epsilon}[& \left(\epsilon a_{11}+a_{21}\right)\otimes b_{12}\otimes \left(c_{12}+\epsilon c_{22}\right)+\\
& \left(\epsilon a_{11}+a_{12}\right)\otimes\left(b_{11}+\epsilon b_{21}\right) \otimes c_{11}-\\
& a_{21}\otimes \left(b_{11}+b_{12} + \epsilon b_{22}\right)\otimes c_{12} -\\
& a_{12}\otimes b_{11}\otimes\left(c_{11} + c_{12} +\epsilon c_{21}\right) +\\
& \left( a_{12}+a_{21}\right)\otimes\left(b_{11}+\epsilon b_{22}\right) \otimes \left(c_{12}+\epsilon c_{21}\right)]\\
\end{align}
For every fixed $\epsilon >0$, this is a tensor of rank at most 5. A direct calculation shows that
$$T(\epsilon) = T_{Bini} + \epsilon \cdot T'$$
for some tensor $T'$, consequently,
$$\lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} T(\epsilon) = T_{Bini}$$
which shows $\underline{R}(T_{Bini}) \leq 5$.$\square$

The last thing we need to do is to show that $\underline{R}(T_{Bini}) \geq 5$. This is a bit more difficult and requires some more involved techniques called *Strassen's equations*. This technique is a quite powerful variation of **Fact 2**. I took everything that follows from [this book by JM Landsberg](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometry-and-complexity-theory/15E3ABA3FF14E1054574663F60250D80).

For that we need some very basic facts about *antisymmetric tensors*. Generally, we see that for a complex vector space $A$, the permutation group $\mathfrak{S}_n$ acts on $A^{\otimes n}$. For $\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n$ we define a linear map $M_\sigma$ by linearly extending
$$M_\sigma : u_1 \otimes \dots \otimes u_n \mapsto u_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \dots \otimes u_{\sigma(n)}$$
to the whole space.

We can define the space $\Lambda^n A$ of antisymmetric tensors in $A^{\otimes n}$ via
$$\Lambda^nA = \lbrace T \in A^{\otimes n}: M_\sigma(T) = \text{sgn}(\sigma)\cdot T \;\;\forall \sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_n\rbrace$$
For $n = 2$, we have the following projection map projecting onto the antisymmetric space:
$$\Pi^\Lambda : A^{\otimes 2} \rightarrow \Lambda^2 A , u_1 \otimes u_2 \mapsto u_1  \wedge u_2 := \frac{1}{2} (u_1 \otimes u_2 - u_2 \otimes u_1) $$
It can be shown that for a $n$ dimensional space $A$ with basis $\lbrace a_1, \dots , a_n \rbrace$, the space $\Lambda^2 A$ has the set $\lbrace a_i \wedge a_j: 1 \leq i < j \leq n \ \rbrace$ as a basis.

Enough about antisymmetric spaces. Recall from **Fact 2** that every tensor $T \in A \otimes B \otimes C$ induces a linear map $T_B : B^* \rightarrow A \otimes C$. Note that we can blow up this map a bit by tensoring it with an identity map: $\text{id}_A \otimes T_B : A \otimes B^* \rightarrow A \otimes A \otimes C$. We define the map
$$T^\wedge_A = \left( \Pi^\Lambda \otimes \text{id}_C \right) \left( \text{id}_A \otimes T_B\right): A \otimes B^* \rightarrow \left(\Lambda^2A \right) \otimes C$$
How does that look like for a rank one tensor $T = u \otimes v \otimes w\in A \otimes B \otimes C$? There,
$$T^\wedge_{A} (x \otimes \beta) = \beta(v) \cdot (x\wedge u) \otimes w$$
for $x \in A$ and $\beta \in B^*$.

If we define a basis of $A$ having the vector $u\in A$ as an element, say $\lbrace u, u_2, \dots, u_n\rbrace$, it is not hard to see that the $(u_i \wedge u)\otimes w$ are linearly independent for $i = 2, \dots , n,$ so we have that $T^\wedge_A$ has rank $n-1$ as a linear map.

For tensors $T_1$ and $T_2$ both in $A \otimes B \otimes C$ we observe that $\left( T_1 + T_2 \right)^\wedge_A = \left( T_1 \right)^\wedge_A + \left( T_2\right)^\wedge_A$ we consequently for a tensor with rank $R(T) = r$ the linear map $T^\wedge_A$ will have rank at most $r\cdot(n -1)$. Since the rank of linear maps is lower semicontinuous, we even know for $\underline{R}(T) = r$ that $T^\wedge_A$ has rank at most $r\cdot(n-1)$. Conclusion: if we calculate the rank of the linear map $T^\wedge_A$, we might be able to lower bound the border rank of $T$!

Indeed, this let's us now finish our little analysis of the Bini tensor:

**Proposition 3:** $\underline{R}(T) \geq 5$ and therefore $\underline{R}(T) = 5$.

**Proof:** Let $r = \underline{R}(T)$ be the border rank of the Bini tensor. By the above discussion, the rank of the linear map $T^\wedge_A$ will be bounded from above by $r \cdot (3-1) = 2\cdot r$. We will now show that $T^\wedge_A$ has rank 10 which proves $2\cdot r \geq 10$, or equivalently, $\underline{R}(T) \geq 5$.

From our basis $\lbrace b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{21}, b_{22}\rbrace$ of $B$ we naturally get a basis $\lbrace \beta_{11}, \beta_{12}, \beta_{21}, \beta_{22}\rbrace$ of $B^*$ by defining
$$\beta_{ij}(b_{kl}) = \begin{cases}1 &\text{ if } (i,j) = (k,l)\\ 0 &\text{ else}\end{cases}$$

Our map $T^\wedge_A$ does the following:
\begin{align}
T^\wedge_A ( a_{ij} \otimes \beta_{kl}) = &\beta_{kl} (b_{11}) \left((a_{ij} \wedge a_{11}) \otimes c_{11}\right)+ \\
&\beta_{kl} (b_{21}) \left((a_{ij} \wedge a_{12}) \otimes c_{11}\right)+ \\
&\beta_{kl} (b_{12}) \left((a_{ij} \wedge a_{11}) \otimes c_{12}\right)+ \\
&\beta_{kl} (b_{22}) \left((a_{ij} \wedge a_{12}) \otimes c_{12}\right)+ \\
&\beta_{kl} (b_{11}) \left((a_{ij} \wedge a_{21}) \otimes c_{21}\right)+ \\
&\beta_{kl} (b_{12}) \left((a_{ij} \wedge a_{21}) \otimes c_{22}\right) 
\end{align}

Probably, the easiest way to check the rank of this linear map is to fix bases and write it as a matrix. For $A \otimes B^*$, we have a basis basis
$$a_{11} \otimes \beta_{11}, \dots, a_{11} \otimes \beta_{22}, a_{12} \otimes \beta_{11}, \dots a_{12} \otimes \beta_{22},  a_{21} \otimes \beta_{11} \dots , a_{21} \otimes \beta_{22}$$
and for $(\Lambda^2A) \otimes C$, we have a basis
$$(a_{11}\wedge a_{12})\otimes c_{11}, \dots ,(a_{11}\wedge a_{12})\otimes c_{22}, (a_{11}\wedge a_{21})\otimes c_{11}, \dots , (a_{11}\wedge a_{21})\otimes c_{22}, (a_{12}\wedge a_{21})\otimes c_{11}, \dots, (a_{12}\wedge a_{21})\otimes c_{22}$$

In these bases, we have e.g.
$$T^\wedge_A:\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = a_{11} \otimes \beta_{11} \mapsto (a_{11}\wedge a_{21})\otimes c_{21} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\\vdots \\0\\1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
where the image is the seventh basis vector and has the 1 in the seventh position. By doing that for all 12 basis vectors, we see that the linear map is in these bases represented by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  & 1&  &-1&  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  & 1&  &-1&  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &-1&  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &-1&  &  \\
1&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & 1&  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &-1&  \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &-1\\
 &  &  &  & 1&  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
 &  &  &  &  & 1&  &  &  &  &  &  \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

which is a $12\times 12$ matrix and has rank 10. Therefore, we are done. $\square$

**Remark:** We said this method is known as *Strassen's equations*. But where are the equations? For this, we make a little detour to algebraic geometry. Define
$$\sigma_r = \lbrace T \in A \otimes B \otimes C: R(T) \leq r \rbrace \subset A \otimes B \otimes C$$
and let $\overline{\sigma_r}$ be the closure of $\sigma_r$ in the Zariski topology. Clearly, the question if $R(T) \leq r$ is equivalent to the question if $T\in \sigma_r$. As it turns out, the question if $\underline{R}(T) \leq r$ is also equivalent to the question $T \in \overline{\sigma_r}$. To show that a tensor has border rank at least $r$, it is therefore enough to show that $T \notin \overline{\sigma_{r-1}}$. As $\overline{\sigma_r}$ are Zariski closed, there are polynomials $p_1, \dots , p_k$ on $A\otimes B\otimes C$ such that
$$\overline{\sigma_r} = \lbrace T \in A \otimes B \otimes C: p_1(T) = 0, \dots , p_k(T) = 0 \rbrace $$
To show that $T \notin \overline{\sigma_r}$, we can in principle always find a polynomial $p$ on $A\otimes B \otimes C$ such that $p$ vanishes on all $\overline{\sigma_r}$ but not on $T$. In the above example, all $10\times 10$-minors of $T^\wedge_A$ vanish on $\overline{\sigma_4}$ but some not on $T$. This explains the name a bit.

This is a self-contained analysis of this specific tensor. One can learn much more about this topic in the lecture notes [Fast Matrix Multiplication](https://www-cc.cs.uni-saarland.de/media/lectures/S13/L-FastMatrixMultiplication/mm.pdf) by Markus Bläser. They are written more from a computer science perspective which is quite different from the language we used in this answer. I found them very instructive and can highly recommend them.

Much more about lower bounds on the border ranks and the geometry of tensor decompositions can be found in the book [Geometry and Complexity Theory](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/geometry-and-complexity-theory/15E3ABA3FF14E1054574663F60250D80) by JM Landsberg. It is an excellent book and covers a gigantic amount of topics.